# Data flow stuck with error message Causes: 606330f83ab24c58

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Got an error message in my **dataflow** job.

I am using 2.1.0 SDK and cloudshell to launch my job.

> (606330f83ab2470f): Workflow failed. Causes: (606330f83ab24c58): The
>   Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to the Dataflow team at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow.

Comment: Can you share the job ID ?

Comment: 2017-11-12_23_05_43-10207672922100781861

Answer (score 0):

Internally, Dataflow failed to create worker instances. The error was :

> [...] Invalid value for field 'resource.properties.networkInterfaces[0].subnetwork': ''. Network interface must specify a subnet if the network resource is in custom subnet mode. [..]

Can you provide --subnetwork option while launching the job? (brief description here : https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.html#getSubnetwork--)

It might look like something like "regions/us-central1/subnetworks/your-network-name-us-central1"

Comment: Still no success.

Comment: While running the job getting this message in mvn console logs.

Comment: `WARNING: Size estimation of the source failed: org.apache.beam.sdk.io.mongodb.MongoDbIO$BoundedMongoDbSource@2bf02168
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=10.240.0.7:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}, `

Comment: `mvn compile exec:java   -Dexec.mainClass=com.stage3.orderlineflattener.StarterPipeline   -Dexec.args="--project=prod-stage3 \
  --stagingLocation=gs://dataflow-prod-stage3/staging/ \
  --output=gs://dataflow-prod-stage3/output \
  --runner=DataflowRunner \
  --jobName=orderlineflattener --network=production-network --subnetwork=regions/us-central1/subnetworks/production-network-us-central1"` This is the command i used to launch the job.

Comment: JobID : 2017-11-15_01_44_52-1965519828718030909 
(ee0cd6626d1969c9): Workflow failed. Causes: (ee0cd6626d19607e): The Dataflow appears to be stuck.  Still getting same error message after 1 hour